# Match height of boxes by class– CSS only, no jQuery or Javascript

Tags: html, css

I have this layout:

[image]

The boxes with an inner red border have class `the-first` and those with an inner blue border have class `the-second`. Each pair also shares an additional class so I can target them as a pair– the first two boxes have class `double-0` and the second two boxes have class `double-1`.

I am looking for a CSS-only solution to match the heights within a given pair so that my layout will look like this:

[image]

I cannot change the structure or, at least, I cannot change it very much. Part of this is because at wider screen widths, I need to match the height of the first three boxes instead of the first two, but I am not trying to solve that issue at the moment. Please also note that the two pairs above are on the same line and have the same parent.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/2qabeh4j/7/).

HTML

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="content">Donec tincidunt dolor a rhoncus elementum. In pharetra mauris sit amet orci mattis porttitor.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">Suspendisse tempor augue et augue egestas convallis. Sed vitae faucibus sem. Quisque aliquet arcu quis nisi dictum lobortis. Aliquam vel fringilla justo.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">Nulla euismod nec elit et vehicula.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">Maecenas placerat pharetra ex, id placerat mi faucibus vel. Pellentesque ultricies quam vel risus scelerisque ultricies. Nulla ultricies lorem suscipit velit fermentum egestas.</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JQUERY

```
    // run this function on each 'content' class, and note the (i)ndex and (el)ement of it
    $('.content').each(function(i, el){
    // if the index number divided by 2 is zero (i.e. it's an even number)
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
    // then add 'the-first' class to the element
            $(this).addClass('the-first');
        } else {
    // if not, then add 'the-second' class to the element
            $(this).addClass('the-second');
        }
    });

    // set a counter
    var count = 0
    // run this function on each 'content' class
    $('.content').each(function() {
    // if the element also has 'the-first' class
            if( $(this).hasClass('content') && $(this).hasClass('the-first') ) {
    // then set the variable 'doubleIndex' that increments the counter by 1 
            var doubleIndex = count++;
    // then add the class 'double-' + the current value of 'doubleIndex'
            $(this).addClass('double-' + doubleIndex);
    // then, go up the DOM tree to the 'li' and from there go to the next 'li' and from there, find the next element with the class 'the-second' and add the class 'double-' + the current value of 'doubleIndex'
            $(this).parents('li').next('li').find('.the-second').addClass('double-' + doubleIndex);

        } else {

        }
    });
```

CSS

```
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    li {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        float: left;
        margin: 0 2px;
        padding: 12px 6px;
        width: calc(25% - 16px);
    }

    .the-first {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .the-second {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

If my jQuery can be improved to improve how CSS targets classes, great, but I do not want it running height calculations.

Much thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: You don't need to post "*all of the code*", but you **must** post the relevant code, including markup **in the question itself**

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can the HTML be altered to wrap each pair in a container?

Comment: Given your current specifications, this is in no way possible. What do you have against a JS solution?

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/4vxw3rag/methin ??

Comment: @Oriol, I don't think so, at wider widths, I need three boxes in a group instead of two

Comment: @Haranguel, I want something truly responsive as the browser width changes, not something that needs to be refreshed when the width changes.

Comment: JS doesn't need the page to be refreshed to get the width changed!!

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, thanks for your help but setting a specific height defeats what I am trying to do which is have the height shrink and grow based on the content of the box with the taller height (within a pair).

Comment: Then it has to be done with javascript

Comment: As Oriol suggested, if you have three, wrap three in each group. If you want to make this happen, you need to do something and I strongly suggest to have them grouped at creation and then using CSS only to keep their height the same. This will have less negative impact on the client and its performance.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick solution is to set specific height

```
.the-first {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
}
.the-second {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```